# What alternate to use for System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode() in .net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am porting a .Net framework built MVC application to .Net Core 3.1 and I have a case where `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode()` methods have been used.

As `System.Web.Helpers` is not available in .Net Core, any idea what alternate to use?

Comment: This should be reopened b/c it asks about .NET Core, not .NET Framework (which is the "duplicate" answeer refers to)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in json serializer (System.Text.Json)

```
var obj = getMyObject();
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way:

- .Net framework @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item))
- .Net 7: @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)) Or JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)